# tf.image.decode_jpeg() returns matrix of zeros

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I am using a script for loading images to TensorFlow which apparently works for everyone, but when I try it, I end up with black image (zero matrix). I tried it with several image files, and it's always zero, and when I deliberately misspell the image location string, it reports an error (as it should). Size of the returned image tensor is correct `(256,256,3)`. This is the script, does someone sees the error?

```
file_names = ['/home/marko/Data/train_27.jpg']
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(file_names)

image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
title, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file,channels=3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    image_tensor = sess.run(image)
    print(image_tensor)
    print(image_tensor.shape)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: same code is working for me. Use the following to display image.  from PIL import Image ; img = Image.fromarray(image_tensor,'RGB') ; img.show()

Comment: I actually did that, but didn't include it here since it wasn't important. Output is just black image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct.
I had the same problem with images from [Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space)

Seems like Tensorflow detects colorspace incorrectly for these files, or the colorspace information encoded in the images is incorrect.

It seems like Tensorflow doesn't allow to enforce colorspace while decoding images. So probably the easiest way is to "fix" the images.

I've used 'convert' utility from ImageMagic toolkit:

```
    ls train-jpg/ | \
        parallel convert -colorspace sRGB train-jpg/{} fixed-train-jpg/{}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution that does not require conversion via command line as suggested by Evgeny, rather uses Pillow for loading the images:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_image(img_path, resize=[256, 256]):

    pil_img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
    img = np.asarray(pil_img) / 255
    img_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)
    img_final = tf.image.resize(img_tensor, resize)
    return img_final
```